# Атрибуты у кнопки в YII

Tags: php, yii

Hi. Думал не придавать значение, но все-таки пытливая голова не дает покоя. Почему CHtml::button() в YII вставляет атрибут name="yi0"?  **Как от этого избавиться?**
Спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

Чисто логически, а вставляет name, чтобы получать данные при POST/GET видимо, иначе как?

```
<?php echo CHtml::button('Button Text', array('name' => 'myCoolNameHere')); ?>
```

Comment: Не знаю как вам, но мне атрибут name в кнопке не нужен. Зачем он там вообще? Бывают ли такие ситуации когда через кнопу передают данные?

Comment: ну как, например у меня есть 3 кнопки и взависимости от того какая нащата я выполню те или иные действия...

Comment: Это может пригодиться например если в одной форме есть кнопки:  
Опубликовать.  
Предпросмотр.  
Сохранить в черновик.  
Форма оправится та же, но в зависимости от кнопки будет разное действие.

Comment: thunder и ReinRaus, спасибо, дошло.